# Is it possible to update an android app while it is running and then reload it again

Tags: android, auto-update

This question might have been asked earlier, but could not get any clear answer. I basically do not want and client interactions with the updates and other stuff, all they can see is the app running and they are happy. But for this to do I need some background thread or something that checks the market for a new update and updates it in the behind and after applying the update reboot the app.

P.S. I am totally new to android development so really sorry if I am sounding crazy, but this is my requirement

Comment: As an android user, I would be suspicious and annoyed at an application that subverted my system setting to disable auto updates. Network traffic isn't always free, and it would also look a lot like malware to the untrained eye. Tread lightly!

Comment: The Play Store app will take care of updating, **if** the user enables auto-update. And me too, I don't want any apps to check for new version. That's redundant.

Comment: @RonDahlgren the app that we are creating is more like an Kiosk App, so our customers only care if it is running properly or not

Comment: @LaiVung know about the Play Store auto update but not sure that if the app is running it will get updated!

Comment: @nipun I think it could be. E.g.: when your app's running in the foreground, the Play Store finds out new update, it shows a toast message on notification bar. The user taps the message to update > the Play Store starts the job > it stops current session of your app to update it.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, it is possible if you have root access, the process is like following:

1. Your app is in `/system/app` folder (as a system app)
2. You need following permissions:

   ```
   android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
   android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES
   android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE
   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS
   ```
3. Your app must be signed with system signature

   ```
   java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 helloworld.apk hello.apk
   ```
4. Check for updates in a background thread and download updated .apk file to a temporary place, e.g `apk_path`
5. Execute `pm install apk_path` command programmatically, below is a snippet:

   ```
   public String silentInstallation(String apkPath)
   {
           String[] args = { "pm", "install", "-r", apkPath };             
           ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);  
           Process process = null;  
           InputStream errIs = null;  
           InputStream inIs = null;  
           try {  
               ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
               int read = -1;  
               process = processBuilder.start();  
               errIs = process.getErrorStream();  
               while ((read = errIs.read()) != -1) {  
                   baos.write(read);  
               }  
               baos.write('\n');  
               inIs = process.getInputStream();  
               while ((read = inIs.read()) != -1) {  
                   baos.write(read);  
               }  
               byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();  
               result = new String(data);  
           } catch (IOException e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
           } catch (Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
           } finally {  
               try {  
                   if (errIs != null) {  
                       errIs.close();  
                   }  
                   if (inIs != null) {  
                       inIs.close();  
                   }  
               } catch (IOException e) {  
                   e.printStackTrace();  
               }  
               if (process != null) {  
                   process.destroy();  
               }  
           }  
           return result;  
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: edited my answer, yes you must make sure your app is in "/system/app".

Comment: Would be nice if you could format your code a bit better. Thanks.

Comment: I had trouble with that (edited 4 or 5 times without success), will try to fix it later..

Comment: @bjzhanghao thnx a lot I will look into this!!

Answer (score 3):

You can not update (or install) an app without user-interaction, unless

1. You're a system app (custom ROM)
2. Your device is rooted and your updater has root privileges.

Further, there is no official API available to check the version of an app available in the Google Play store.

You can achieve some of what you are trying to do by keeping track of the current version outside of Google Play and then prompting to update the user by launching the market link. If you do that from a secondary app, you can even wait for the update to be complete and then re-launch the app.

In practice, you can't do silent installs/updates without user-interaction, and that's a Good Thing (tm), for the reasons that the first couple of commenters have stated.